# Xlsxwriter cant find file for close() in Django Project

Tags: python, django, xlsxwriter

I am attempting to write a class to create an excel sheet using my Django Models. I have created the following class:

```
class workBook(object):

def __init__(self, title, data):
    path = '\\workbooks\\' + title + '.xlsx'
    print(os.path.normpath(path))
    self.workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(os.path.normpath(path))
    newWorkSheet(self.workbook, data)
    self.workbook.close()
```

The method creates the workbook with the proper path but when I close it I get the following error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\workbooks\\Test.xlsx'
```

I know this is because of the double "\" but I dont know how to send the correct path to the close method. I also know the rest of my class works because it does not throw this error when I simply put the file name and not a full directory.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by just using "/" instead of "\" in a custom path.